# Google Spreadsheet Dynamic Hyperlink

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I am trying to create a dynamic hyperlink that checks references cell "J2" and checks "Options!B4:BI14" range for a match.  I am trying to get the label to be the matching cells value, and the link to go to the cell.

Using the below formula I am getting the right label, right cell, and right link address, but its still not opening the sheet and linking to the cell when I click on it

```
=HYPERLINK(SUBSTITUTE("#"&CELL("address",index(Options!B4:BI14,Match(Options!B4,Options!B4:B14,0),Match(J2,Options!B8:BI8,0))),"$",""),index(Options!B4:BI14,Match(Options!B4,Options!B4:B14,0),Match(J2,Options!B8:BI8,0)))
```

Is there an easier way to accomplish what I am trying to do?

Comment: Excel or Google Sheets? Please use the correct tags.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Answer (score 0):

you do miss a **`gid`** and you should use **`range`**.  example:

[image]